# How to create a regular expression that pulls from two line groups?

Tags: c#, regex

I am having trouble writing a regular expression to pull one element from one line and another element from another line, but I can't seem to get it to pull from both.

Here is the text I am parsing with my regular expression (c# flavour):

```
    [MessageTypeName("add-message")]
    public class AddSystemRequestMessage : Message
    {
    }

    [MessageTypeName("add-accept")]
    public class AddAcceptMessage : Message
    {
    }

    [MessageTypeName("add-progress")]
    public class AddProgressMessage : Message
    {
    }
```

My goal is to parse this code and grab the following (numbers are groups):

```
1. add-message
2. AddSystemRequestMessage

1. add-accept
2. AddAcceptMessage

1. add-progress
2. AddProgressMessae
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I get that right.

```
\[MessageTypeName\("([^"]+)"\)\]\s+public\s+class\s+([^:\s]+)
```

There are many snares in this solution. It won't match

- escaped strings like `[MessageTypeName("x\"y")]`
- if there are other attributes between `MessageTypeName` and `public class`
- if the class is not `public`
- if the attribute has multiple and/or named parameters
- if there's something similar inside a string
- ...

You name it!

I propose to use named groups

```
\[MessageTypeName\("(?<type>[^"]+)"\)\]\s+public\s+class\s+(?<class>[^:\s]+)
```

It's just less trouble...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
\[MessageTypeName\("([^"]+)"\)\]\s*\w+\s+class\s+([^\s:]+)
```

This regex will also work if your class signature contains `private`, not only `public`.

Regex explanation:

- `\[MessageTypeName\("` - Match literal `[MessageTypeName("`
- `([^"]+)` - Match 1 or more character other than double quote
- `"\)` - Match a double quote and a literal `)`
- `\]` - Match a literal `]`
- `\s*` - Match any number of whitespace including a newline
- `\w+` - Match `public` or `private` or just 1 or more alphanumeric chars and `_`
- `\s+` - Match 1 or more whitespace including a newline
- `class` - Match `class` substring
- `\s+` - Match 1 or more whitespace including a newline
- `([^\s:]+)` Capture the class name consisting of anything other than a whitespace and a colon.

The values you are looking for are in Group 1 and Group 2.

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5BMessageTypeName%5C(%22(%5B%5E%22%5D%2B)%22%5C)%5C%5D%5Cs*%5Cw%2B%5Cs%2Bclass%5Cs%2B(%5CS%2B)&i=%5BMessageTypeName(%22add-message%22)%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20class%20AddSystemRequestMessage%20%3A%20Message%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BMessageTypeName(%22add-accept%22)%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20class%20AddAcceptMessage%20%3A%20Message%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BMessageTypeName(%22add-progress%22)%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20class%20AddProgressMessage%20%3A%20Message%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)

C# sample code:

```
var str = "[MessageTypeName(\"add-message\")]\n    public class AddSystemRequestMessage : Message\n    {\n    }";
var rx = new Regex(@"\[MessageTypeName\(""([^""]+)""\)\]\s*\w+\s+class\s+([^\s:]+)");
var matches = rx.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(p => new[] { p.Groups[1].Value, p.Groups[2].Value }).ToList();
```

Output:

[image]

If the type names are unique, you'd better create a `Dictionary` object:

```
var matches = rx.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(t => new string[] { t.Groups[1].Value, t.Groups[2].Value }).ToDictionary(t => t[0], t => t[1]);
```

[image]

Comment: Nice question. If you need more assistance, please feel free to ask. If you want to expand the regex, I hope my explanation makes it easy to apply any changes to it. Anyway, feel free to ask for help.